# Working fine with wifi network but not working with mobile network

Tags: android

My android studio app login working fine with wifi network but having problems with mobile networks. Can any tell me what is exact problem is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Check ‘Data Usage’ in the Settings app and look for apps with limited data access